# Finding out where some code in a LINQPad query is defined

Tags: c#, linqpad

I have the following C# code segment in a LINQPad query:

```
.Select(x => new LocationDistrict
    { ...
```

When I hover over `LocationDistrict`, the tooltip displays:

*LINQPad.User.LocationDistrict*

[image]

How can I find out where User.LocationDistrict is being pulled in from?  In the right-click context menu, the *Go to definition F12* option is greyed out.

Comment: Have you paid for a license for LINQPad? That's the way you get the "Go to definition" menu option. You'll need to show us more code, and tell us what libraries you've linked to, to answer the rest of the question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes, we have site license, I am running latest paid version 5.26.01.

Comment: You'll need to show us more code, and tell us what libraries you've linked to, to answer the rest of the question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have since been told that linq2sql is involved.  Indeed, LocationDistrict is a table in the database that the code is querying.  But I don't understand how LINQPad knows how to create a LocationDistrict object from some table in the database.

Comment: That's part of its magic. Honestly, it's not that hard; it just reads the schema of your database; for each table, it creates an object named for the table (there are certain rules it follows), then for each column it creates a property.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Please post it as an answer so I can close the question.  Thanks very much.  (But I still don't understand where/how "User" comes into this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: LINQPad automatically generates classes based on tables in your connected database. The classes for rows in each table are placed in the `LINQPad.User` namespace.

For instance, in the following examples I'm using the AdventureWorks2012 database. When I connect to it, I can see a number of "tables" in the Connection pane:

[image: Tables in AdventureWorks2012]

I can drag those over to the Query window and start a query:

[image: LINQ methods show up on tables]

The type of Addresses in this case is `System.Data.Linq.Table<Address>`, where `Address` is of type `LINQPad.User.Address`:

[image: Showing type of individual records is under LINQPad.User]

So, it appears as though `LocationDistrict` in your case is a mapping of an individual record in the table of a similar name. It would be called `LocationDistricts` in the Connection pane, but since LINQPad does some naming normalization, could be called `LOCATION_DISTRICT` in your actual database.

I guess the makers of LINQPad needed some place to put these types (to avoid naming conflicts), and settled on `LINQPad.User` as an acceptable namespace.